# async each series does not return as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

Im using async library, specifically the each method, but Im not getting the expected result.

```
 function instanceMethod (final_callback) {
        obj = this;
        async.parallel([
            function (callback) {
                getTopReplies (obj, function (err, result){
                    if (err) return callback(err);
                    if (result) {
                        obj.topReplies = result;
                        callback();
                    }
                });
            }
            // ... theres actually more 2 functions here but
            // I removed them for the sake of space and
            // readability,
         ], function (err){
            if (err) return final_callback(err, false);
            return final_callback (false, true);
        });
```

This is the function Im calling from an async.parallel list of functions

```
function getTopReplies (obj, callback) {
    mongoose.model('Post').find({replyTo: obj._id, draft: false})
    .limit(3).sort('-createdAt')
    .exec(function(err, tops) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        var result = [];
        if (tops) {
            async.eachSeries(tops, function(top, callback) {
                result.push(top._id);
                callback();
            }, function (err){
                if (err) return callback(err);
                return callback(null, result);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

theres a case where result should return two top posts id in the array but it always returns 1 or if theres only 1 top reply to a post it returns empty.

Is there anything wrong on my code?

Is the result array to be initiated somewhere else, like is it getting reinitiated everytime, the each function is called or something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look to me like you need the async.parallel call. It really only makes sense to use that when you pass more than one function. You're essentially saying "Do this ONE task in parallel." Try this:

```
function instanceMethod (final_callback) {
    obj = this;
    getTopReplies (obj, function (err, result){
        if (err) return final_callback(err, false);
        if (result) {
            obj.topReplies = result;
            return final_callback (false, true);
        }
    });
});
```

I'm not saying that will resolve your issue. But removing unnecessary asynchronous/callback complexity makes it a whole lot easier to debug.

For that matter, you could probably get rid of the async.eachSeries as well if you use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/). It has a helpful `pluck` method for doing basically what you're doing.

```
function getTopReplies (obj, callback) {
    mongoose.model('Post').find({replyTo: obj._id, draft: false})
    .limit(3).sort('-createdAt')
    .exec(function(err, tops){
        if (err) return callback(err);
        if (tops) return callback(null, _.pluck(tops, _id)); // Assuming you declare _ earlier in the module
    });
}
```

With all the unnecessary async out of the way, it should be a lot easier to figure out what's going wrong. Possibly it's because you named both callbacks "callback." It LOOKS like it shouldn't have mattered (because of scoping), but with async, it's always safer to name them different things just to be sure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, about it I just took out the other 2 operations in order to show what was important, thats why Im using the async.parallel. I did change the eachSeries to just each, and testing it, and it works but if I try and make a bunch of posts go through this process some will have the correct data some will not, which is just kind of weird!

Comment: Is there anything in common with the ones that do (or do not) work correctly?

Comment: theyre different queries, and theres it should not return an array but a simple string (id) value, and yeah those work.

Comment: marking this as the answer, it gave me lots of insight! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

not sure your exact issue but why are are you using an async.eachSeries instead of

```
var result = [];
if (tops){
  tops.forEach(function(top){
    result.push(top._id);
  });
};
return callback(null,result);
```

if I understand it right your just copying the ids into a new array this is a synchronous operation

Comment: Synchronous is different from blocking. array.forEach is blocking whereas async.eachSeries just iterates in series (as the name suggests).

Comment: valid point I wasn't considering a case where the array would be large enough for the blocking to matter.